# Error writing to a pointer that solves by changing pointer to array. What's happening?

Tags: c, mingw, clion

So I was programming a sudoku solver in C, and I came up with something I didn't expect.

The sudoku was stored as a global pointer to a char.

```
char *sudoku=
        "200050713"
        "431000805"
        "675800094"
        "016075000"
        "740268901"
        "052914037"
        "527600109"
        "164090382"
        "080102006";
```

At some point of the program naturally I had to write to the array, to keep it simple (and legal) let's say:

```
sudoku[1] = '1';
```

I am receiving a SIGSEGV at that line. This solves by just changing the type of the global variable sudoku to an array.

```
char sudoku[] = ...
```

There aren't any other variables or functions named sudoku if you are wondering.
I'm curious about this behavior, is a global pointer read-only?

Comment: Those 9 strings are all concatenated by the compiler as a 1-D array, with a pointer to it. The string is read-only but the pointer isn't (meaning it can be changed to point to something else). By using `char sudoku[] = ...` that string was *copied* to the read/write array.

Comment: `SIGSEGV` is caused when you have a memory access violation. You're trying to modify a `const char*`. By changing it to an array, you are copying the `const char*` data to a `char` array

Comment: @JL2210 I did not mention a stack. Your comment added more detail, but what part of my comment was wrong? If that was a local variable, the data would be copied when the function is called.

Comment: @WeatherVane The question states that it's a global variable, so it's not copied. It would just be a pointer to somewhere in the program data. Unless I'm misinterpreting your comment, and you meant the pointer was copied.

Comment: @JL2210 that's true, but *when* the data is copied into a global array isn't really relevant: by the compiler, the linker, or the executor, but at some stage, it is. I did overlook the "global" part. I meant the *data* is copied into `char sudoko[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm curious about this behaviour, is a global pointer read-only?

It has nothing to do with globals. Invokding `char *s = "asdf"` creates an array in read only memory and the points the pointer `s` to it. Well, to be more accurate it's not necessarily read only memory, but it could be, and irregardless it's undefined behavior trying to write to it. It's about the same as doing this:

```
const char arr[] = "asdf";
char *s = arr;
```

Your second attempt, however, initializes an array, and notice how similar it is to the first line in the above snippet. Just remove `const` and you have the same.